# Subscribe is deprecated: Use an observer instead

Tags: javascript, angular

Code from angular 13, I just don't know what should i do here,

```js
 public createAccount(userObj:any){
    return new Promise<any>((resolve,rejects)=>{
      this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users',userObj).subscribe(
     (res)=>{
        resolve(res);
      },
      (err)=>{
        rejects(err);
      }
      );
    }
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [an observer](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observer) instead:

```
this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/users", userObj).subscribe({
  next: (res) => {
    resolve(res);
  },
  error: (err) => {
    rejects(err);
  },
});
```

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Can you please elaborate on your question? I don't think I understood it properly.

Comment: Nope, I misread the answer and did not understand it. It is good actually

Comment: (I could not find the difference between the 2 pieces of code and could not find where the observer was)